# Right click not working in Redhat enterprise Linux

Tags: rhel-5, linux-device-driver

I have recently installed Red hat enterprise Linux on my Hp laptop. Earlier both the mouse clicks were not working, but I managed to get the left click working by tapping by some help from Google. But still I can click only using tapping. And the actual left-click and right-click buttons are not working. Are there any drivers I am supposed to install?

Comment: RHEL 5 has an old kernel which lacks support for many new drivers. I'd recommend to install something new, like RHEL 6.3 (though its kernel is not bleeding-edge either).